# php OOP construct() arguments

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP. I have been using a class that has 2 functions in:

```
class department{
public $departmentid;
function __construct($todestroy){
    $this->departmentid = $todestroy;
}

function viewDeptFunct(){
    require_once "../db/class_db_connect.php";
    require_once "../config.php";
    $fetch_view_sql = "SELECT * FROM department WHERE id = '$this->departmentid'";
    $fetch_view_dept_sql = $db->prepare($fetch_view_sql);
    $fetch_view_dept_sql->execute();
    $fetch_view_dep_result = $fetch_view_dept_sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $fetch_view_dep_result;
}

function editDeptFunct($name,$emailaddress,$password){
    require "../db/class_db_connect.php";
    require "../config.php";
    $edit_sql = "UPDATE department SET name = '$name', emailaddress = '$emailaddress', password = '$password' WHERE id = '$this->departmentid';";
    $edit_dept_sql = $db->prepare($edit_sql);
    $edit_dept_sql->execute();
}
```

My instantiator goes like this:

```
$dept = new department($_GET['id']);
$dept_var = $dept->viewDeptFunct();
if(isset($_POST['edited'])){
$dept->editDeptFunct($_POST['name'],$_POST['emailaddress'],$_POST['password']);
}
```

I am trying to get the instantiator to work while allowing the `viewDeptFunct()` function to work too but I don't know how. Please can someone advise me.

My thinking is that they would have to go in the construct function but how since the viewDeptFunct() only allows 1 argument?

Comment: Sidenote: If you're going to use PDO, use a prepared statement.  In its present state, your code is open to an SQL injection. While hoping you're not storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `viewDeptFunc` doesn't take any arguments. It looks to me like the code should work, what problem are you having?

Comment: @Fred-ii- He is using a prepared statement, ITYM he should use parameters instead of string substitution.

Comment: You should probably call `editDeptFunct` before `viewDeptFunct`. Otherwise, `$dept_var` will contain the values before it was edited.

Comment: The problem Im having is that the SQL is showing up with blank values except for the departmentid. I have no idea why because OOP is new and confusing to me. Also this is only example code for learning and no sanitisation/injection prevention is taking place because I know how to put that in.

Comment: @Barmar, my question is, am I doing it correctly? It just doesn't look right, I thought the point of a construct was for variables to be passed to the class but when I tried (just like `viewDeptFunct`) `viewDeptFunct` then fails because there are too many arguments

Answer (score 0):

Technically this question is invalid as the fix wasn't anything to do with the classes or PHP for that matter. I forgot to put `name=""` properties in my HTML form. Once I had put them in place and named them correctly, everything worked as expected.